# Is LinkedList.toString().replace() O(2*k)?

Tags: java, replace, tostring

I know that converting a suitable object (e.g., a linked list) to a string using the toString() method is an O(n) operation, where 'n' is the length of the linked list. However, if you wanted to then replace something in that that string using the replace(), method, is that also an o(k) method, where 'k' is the length of the string?

For example, for the line `String str = path.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "");`, does this run through the length of the linked list 1 time, and then the length of the string an additional 3 times? If so, is there a more efficient way to do what that line of code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would. `replace` has no idea that `[` and `]` are only found at the start and end. In fact, it's worse - you get another loop for copying the string over (the string has an underlying array and that needs to be cloned in its entirety to lop a character out of it).

If your intent is to replace every `[` in the string, then, no, there is no faster way. However, if your actual intent is to simply not have the opening brace and closing brace, then either write your own loop to toString the contents. Something like:

```
LinkedList<Foo> foos = ...;

StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (Foo f : foos) out.append(out.length() == 0 ? "" : ", ").append(f);
return out.toString();
```

Or even:

```
String.join(", ", foos);
```

Or even:

```
foos.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

None of this is the same thing as `.replace("[", "")` - after all, if a `[` symbol is part of the toString() of any `Foo` object, it would be stripped out as well with `.replace("[", "")` - though you probably didn't want that to happen.

Note that the way modern CPUs work, unless that list has over a few thousand elements in it, looping it 4 times is essentially free and takes no measurable time. The concept of `O(n)` 'kicks in' after a certain number of loops. On modern hardware, it tends to be *a lot* of loops before it matters. Often other concerns are much more important. As a simple example, linked list, in general? Horrible performance relative to something like ArrayList. Even in cases where O(k) wise it should be faster. It's due to the way linkedlists create extra objects and how these tend to be non-contiguous (not near each other in memory). Modern CPUs can't read memory at all. They can ask the memory controller to take one of the on-die cache pages and replace it with the contents of another memory page, which takes 500 to a 1000 cycles. The CPU will ask the memory controller to do that and then go to sleep for 1000 cycles. You can see how reducing the number of times it does this can have a rather marked effect on performance, and yet the `O(k)` business doesn't and cannot take it into account.

Do not worry about performance unless you have a real life scenario where the program appears to run slower than you think it should. Then, use a profiler to figure out which 1% of the code is eating 99% of the resources (because it's virtually always a 1% 'hot path' that is responsible) and then optimize just that 1%. It's pretty much impossible to predict what the 1% is going to be. So, don't bother trying to do so while writing code, it just leads you to writing harder to maintain, less flexible code - which ironically enough tends to lead to situations where adjusting the hot path is *harder*. Worrying about performance, in essence, *slows down the code*. Hence why it's very very important not to worry about that, and worry instead about code that is easy to read and easy to modify.

Comment: This is more knowledge than I ever could have asked for! Thank you for your insight.